# Variables not detected by test template with Robot Framework

Tags: python, robotframework, data-driven-tests

I've been experimenting with Data-Driven style in Robot Framework, and I found out that it struggles a bit when using variables to fix an argument. I'll explain better with an example.

From the [Robot Framework User Guide](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#data-driven-style), you can find this test case, where the template gets fixed the `${expected}` argument to `3`, and then some test are listed with a data-driven structure:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Template with embedded arguments
    [Template]    The result of ${calculation} should be 3
    1 + 2    
    4 - 1    

*** Keywords ***
The result of ${calculation} should be ${expected}
    ${result} =    Evaluate    ${calculation}
    Should Be Equal    ${result}     ${expected}
```

But, if you are using a variable to define the value to be fixed, then the test template will not be able to detect that variable:

```
*** Variables ***
${value}    3

*** Test Cases ***
Template with embedded arguments
    [Template]    The result of ${calculation} should be ${value}
    1 + 2    
    4 - 1    

*** Keywords ***
The result of ${calculation} should be ${expected}
    ${result} =    Evaluate    ${calculation}
    Should Be Equal    ${result}     ${expected}
```

Theoretically, the value of my variable should be replaced for the `${expected}` argument, but instead I get the following error when running the test:

```
Keyword 'The result of ${calculation} should be ${expected}' expected 0 arguments, got 1.
```

Somehow, the interpreter detects my variable as an extra argument. Someone would say that this happens because the keyword ends with this variable, but no extra spaces where added, and I've tried with other situations where my fixed argument is inside the keyword and not at its end, and the same error raises.

By now, the only "solution" I found to successfully use my variable was to include it in every test case, as showed below:

```
*** Variables ***
${value}    3

*** Test Cases ***
Template with embedded arguments
    [Template]    The result of ${calculation} should be ${expected}
    1 + 2    ${value}    
    4 - 1    ${value}

*** Keywords ***
The result of ${calculation} should be ${expected}
    ${result} =    Evaluate    ${calculation}
    Should Be Equal    ${result}     ${expected}
```

But of course, this approach loses all the advantages of using fixed arguments.

Does someone know how to deal with this issue? Thanks in advance for any response!

Comment: What is the point of embeding the arguments in the keyword if only use it once in the template anyway? For specifying the individual test you don´t use the keyword, but just the arguments them selves.

Comment: The purpose is to be able to easily test some other values. It can't be think in this case, as it is a simple add, but as I said, it was just an example. In a real situation, I'd have more test cases and using variables would improve my tests.

Comment: I understand that but why do you need those arguments embeded in the keyword? When use the keyword as a template you only type the keyword once and than you use just the arguments them self to make the test. It is not about complexity of the example...